# Function to make Node of linkedlist to last node?

Tags: c, linked-list

This function will take a particular node of linked list and make it Last node.

```
void lastNode(struct list *node)
{
  struct list* temp = node->next;
  node->next = NULL;
  struct list* temp2;
  while(temp)
    {

      temp2 = temp->next;
      printf("%p \n",temp);
      free(temp);
      temp = temp2;
    }

}

int main()
{
  struct list d={4,NULL};
  struct list c={3,&d};
  struct list b={2,&c};
  struct list a={1,&b};


  struct list *node = &a;

  lastNode(&b);

  while(node)
    {
      printf("%d \n",node->d);
      node=node->next;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

but it is giving me error in freeing a node.

Comment: What error...? It like - "it's not working, help me" or "Doctor, some part of my body hurts, give me universal medicine, that will fix it"..

Comment: @Kiril http://codepad.org/QC8b0uHU Segmentation fault in loop

Comment: this is something else now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your full code:

```
struct list c={3,&d};
struct list b={2,&c};

lastNode(&b);
```

It is not legal to `free` `temp` since it wasn't allocated using `malloc`.

```
struct list* temp = node->next; /* temp is now &c. You can't free it. */
while(temp)
{
    /* ... */  
    free(temp); /* Tries to free &c which is on the stack. */
}
```

Comment: Even if the nodes were allocated using malloc, temp is only used to iterate through the list and does not "own" the node.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This was written before the caller of the free function was provided.  Now that I see this I would say that yeah, you can't call `free` on a stack address.  However my original answer is preserved below, about how to better do a list removal...

---

I don't see a `free` bug pop out at me suddenly, but....  it seems like this approach will only work if the `node` passed in is the first node. If it's some node other than the first you will need a pointer to the previous one so you can set `prev->next = node->next`.

Actually, thinking about this more... If all you're doing is taking a node and making it the last one, why do you need to `free` anything?  It seems like this code frees the entire list starting from `temp`.  If that is your intention I recommend something more like this:

```
void free_all_at_node(struct list **list, struct list *node_to_free)
{
   struct list *n = *list, *prev = NULL;

   // Search for node_to_free, updating prev to indicate the last node we saw.
   //
   while (n && n != node_to_free)
   {
      prev = n;
      n = n->next;
   }

   // Check to see if we found it...
   //
   if (n == node_to_free)
   {
      // Do we have a previous node?
      //
      if (prev)
      {
         // Yes, update next pointer...
         //
         prev->next = NULL;
      }
      else
      {
         // This is the start of the list.  Update the head...
         //
         *list = NULL;
      }

      // Now free stuff...
      //
      while (n)
      {
         struct list *next = n->next;
         free(n);
         n = next;
      }
   }
}
```

That assumes you want `node_to_free` to be the first node to free, and hence we search for it given the start of the list.  Another alternative is to have the caller specify the node *before* the first node to free.  (It looks like your code is actually trying to do this...)  I might prefer to do it like this:

```
void free_after_node(struct list *n)
{
   // If the node is NULL or has no next node, there is nothing to do.
   //
   if (n && n->next)
   {
      // Start at the node after the first, since we want to keep the first
      // one around.
      //
      n = n->next;

      // Now free...
      //
      while (n)
      {
         struct list *next = n->next;
         free(n);
         n = next;
      }
   }
}
```